# Angularjs :- Best Practices for filling combobox

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs.I have scenario where I fill all my combo box by a service which do an Ajax call ($http get method with different url request- data is different for each combo box) How will it effect my application. Is there any better way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular removes the necessity for you to specifically map the data directly to the element, you just have to get the data into your $scope and Angular takes care of the rest.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="o.text for o in selectOptions"></select>
```

And then in your controller:

```
$http.get(url).then(function (result) {
    $scope.selectOptions = result.data;
});
```

The dropdown will just have no items in it until after the HTTP request completes, at which point the dirty-checking will cause the UI to update itself.

Of course, it would be smart to isolate your HTTP calls into a shared service if the same data is used all over the place.